# Postgres FK referencing composite PK INSERT VIOLATION

Tags: postgresql, insert

I am trying to insert into a table (mdata) which has a compost foreign key referencing to a primary keys in another table (measurement), unfortunately I have this error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "mdata" violates foreign key constraint "FK_mdata"
DETAIL:  Key (time, measurement_id)=(2022-07-18 12:35:03.31052, 1) is not present in table "measurement".
SQL state: 23503
```

Note that the foreign key data exist surly in the reference table. below are my two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.mdata
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    value jsonb NOT NULL,
    measurement_id bigint NOT NULL,
    "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_medata" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_mdata" FOREIGN KEY ("time", measurement_id)
        REFERENCES public.measurement ("time", id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.measurement
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    value real NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_measurement" PRIMARY KEY ("time", id),

 )
```

the problem is that I don't see the issue, because I am sure what I am inserting into mdata (measurement_id  and "time") surly exist in the measurement  table. Could someone give a hint about the problem ?

I am trying to insert like this

```
INSERT INTO public.mdata(
id, value, measurement_id, "time")
VALUES (8, '{}',1 , '2022-07-18 12:35:03.31052');
```

Comment: You are sure that the referenced values exist, but Postgres is sure they are not; who do we believe?

Comment: We believe both! the inheritance in table measurement was causing the INSERT VIOLATION.  since I am working with pgadmin there was no documentation about small icon and delayed me from knowing the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380010/right-arrow-on-the-table-tree-in-pgadmin/73038681#73038681

Answer (score 0):

After investigation the only possible reason for this, it that the table measurement might be an inherited table, thanks to @Craig Ringer for this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360312/foreign-keys-table-inheritance-in-postgresql), which pushed me to double check if there is any inheritance to my table:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS

So, indeed, the inheritance was causing the INSERT VIOLATION.